# Question about diffusion current in semiconductor?

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics, diffusion

I'm reading semiconductor physics by Neamen and when the disscusion about the diffusion current density he wrote this (I'll cite the image from the book because it has an important graph  that will help in clarifying the question)

[image]

My question is: How did he say that half of electrons at $x=-l$ will pass the the area at $x=0$? if the diffusion goes from high concentration to low concentration ,the how electrons from $x=-l$ will pass at $x=0$ and it's obviously that $n(x=0)>n(x=-l)$?

correct me if I said anything wrong

Comment: Diffusion going from high concentration to low concentration is the result of a large number of random walks throughout the material. If each step is random, half will be in one direction and half in the other (for a 1-D problem).

Comment: @Joncuster 
I understand this but how the lower in concentration will go to the higher ?

Comment: In a random walk, atoms in the lower concentration region go both left and right. The _net_ movement is from high to low concentration, but that does not imply that no atoms move from low to high.

Comment: Diffusion current is a result of the fact that there are more carriers randomly making their way from $x = \ell$ toward $x = 0$ than from $x = -\ell$ toward $x = 0$, just by virtue of there being more carriers at $x = \ell$ than at $x = -\ell$. It's not because the random motion of the carriers at $x = \ell$ is preferentially toward the left, or vice versa.